# URL pattern mapping

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a jsp whose url pattern is /data/viewableImage.jsp

Is there a way in the url pattern to have the jsp be called even if the user does not include the .jsp part of the url?

So if they navigate to /data/viewableImage the page is still called?

Thanks

Comment: how do you map urls ?

Comment: what I mean is in the web.xml file, I have the url pattern /data/viewableImage.jsp mapped to a JSP.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your jsp pages in a common path like `/WEB-INF` users won't be able to request the jsp pages and you can use a Servlet to add the jsp extension.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>data</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mypackage.JSPAggregationServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>data</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The JSPAggregationServlet Servlet will have to forward the request to the JSP page by only including en .jsp extension.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF" + request.getPathInfo() + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
```

**Example:**

```
Request /data/car/search
Response: /data/car/search.jsp
```

Comment: what happens if they actually do navigate to /data/car/search.jsp?

Comment: Why whould they go to that page?. You can update the service to handle those cases but the jsp pages won't be available for users to access directly, you hide them under /WEB-INF